# Understanding ruby case statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Here is my code first

```
  def participation_earning(partcpnt_usr)
    case show_participant_users
    when Array
      puts "***********Inside Array Statement - #{Time.now} *********"
      sleep 1
      show_participant_users.find do |show_prtcpnt_usr|
        show_prtcpnt_usr.show_participant_id == partcpnt_usr.participant_id
      end
    when ActiveRecord::Relation
      puts "***********Inside Relation Statement - #{Time.now} *********"
      sleep 1
      show_participant_users.where(:show_participant_id => partcpnt_usr.participant_id).first
    else
      puts "Will always go in else part"  
    end  
  end
```

Few explanation `show_participant_users` is a relation object on user something like 
`@user.show_participant_users`

Now what bothering me is that even though the class for `show_participant_users` is an Array it still goes into else block no idea why (just to confirm `show_participant_users` is not `nil` it an Array)

on the contrary the below code work as expected

```
array_fields = []

case array_fields
 when Array
  puts "Ruby Array"
 when Hash
  puts "Ruby Hash"
end
```

any idea other then if/else statement which I dont want to use because of brevity

Thanking You

Comment: If it's a relationship, it's not an array.

Comment: puts `show_participant_users.class` and check that it's indeed a subclass of `Array`.

Comment: @DaveNewton very well taken said my mistake on explaining it Array part is at the time of creating `new_record` thanks for correcting it

Comment: class is a method like any other - it can be overridden to "lie"

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
case show_participant_users.class
```

For example:

```
array_fields = User.where("id > 5").limit(2) #return the array
array_fields.class #gives ActiveRecord::Relation and not Array
```

Comment: thanks but `case` internally does the class comparsion something like `===` so `.class` wouldnt make sense just run the code attach at the end in the `irb`

Comment: Results from ActiveRecord calls are never arrays, until they are eval'ed, like printed in console etc.

Comment: @rewritten I mention in above comment that Array is used at time of creating new object any other time  it relation object and it both the case I seem to execute the else part

Comment: @Salil thanks once again the Case statement also has "ActiveRecord::Relation" class matcher

Comment: ActiveRecord results are arrays via a proxy.  The proxy disguises itself as an array, e.g. `results.class` etc.

Answer (score 0):

You should print your object's class and ancestors in console, to be sure that the class is what you expect.

From the syntax, it's a method call, so it may have unexpected class.

Answer (score 0):

```
def participation_earning(partcpnt_usr) 
 case partcpnt_usr
 when Array
   puts "***********Inside Array Statement - #{Time.now} *********"
   sleep 1
   show_participant_users.find do |show_prtcpnt_usr|
      show_prtcpnt_usr.show_participant_id == partcpnt_usr.participant_id
    end
  when ActiveRecord::Relation
   puts "***********Inside Relation Statement - #{Time.now} *********"
   sleep 1
   show_participant_users.where(:show_participant_id => partcpnt_usr.participant_id).first
  else
    puts "Will always go in else part"  
  end  
end
```